# Javascript not working in MVC project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using a template in an ASP.NET MVC project. Template is here - http://themeforest.net/item/lagu-admin-premium-template/687301

All seems to be working apart from the tabs script. This works in the plain html version but in my MVC project it doesn't work.

This is the script at the end of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        head.js(
            "/Content/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js",
            "/Content/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js",
            "/Content/lib/harvesthq-chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js",
            "/Content/lib/fusion-charts/FusionCharts.js",
            "/Content/lib/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js",
            "/Content/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js",
            "/Content/lib/file-uploader/fileuploader.js",
            "/Content/lib/tiny-mce/jquery.tinymce.js",
            "/Content/js/jquery.microaccordion.js",
            "/Content/js/jquery.tools.min.js",
            "/Content/js/jquery.stickyPanel.js",
            "/Content/js/xbreadcrumbs.js",
            "/Content/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js",
            "/Content/js/lagu.js",
            function(){
                lga_fusionCharts.chart_k();
                lga_wizard.init();
                lga_flowTabs.tabs_b();
                lga_selectBox.init();
                lga_datepicker.init();
                lga_editor.init();
                lga_sticky.sticky_contentActions();
                lga_clearForm.init();
                lga_form_a_validation.init();
            }
        )
    </script>
```

When I view source the correct location is there for the lagu.js file but the lga_flowTabs function doesn't appear to be working.

The html version is exactly the same but without the 'Content' folder.

Is there anyway I can debug this and figure out why the function isn't being hit in the MVC app?

Thanks

Comment: What does your browser's Javascript debugger/console window say?

Comment: Can you provide any kind of error message or anything?

Comment: Generally, jQuery.js has to be included in your head section as a real tag.  It doesn't like being at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this, if the file using this code is a cshtml (Assuming you're using Razor on MVC3 project)

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        head.js(
            "@Url.Content("~/Content/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/lib/harvesthq-chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/lib/fusion-charts/FusionCharts.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/lib/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/lib/file-uploader/fileuploader.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/lib/tiny-mce/jquery.tinymce.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/js/jquery.microaccordion.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/js/jquery.tools.min.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/js/jquery.stickyPanel.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/js/xbreadcrumbs.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js")",
            "@Url.Content("/Content/js/lagu.js")",
            function(){
                lga_fusionCharts.chart_k();
                lga_wizard.init();
                lga_flowTabs.tabs_b();
                lga_selectBox.init();
                lga_datepicker.init();
                lga_editor.init();
                lga_sticky.sticky_contentActions();
                lga_clearForm.init();
                lga_form_a_validation.init();
            }
        )
    </script>
```

Also, maybe silly question but, shouldn't your scripts be on the `Scripts` folder instead of `Content`?